# JBoss ESB, JBRMS and JBPM

Tags: jboss, drools, esb, jbpm

Can anyone suggest books to understand writing rules looking upon business process and integrating that into ESB? I know how to write a rule and run a java application. That is where I reached for last 2 days. Anything useful will help me in catching up with all these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check the jbpm.org documentation site and the drools.org documentation site?
I'm promoting a Community Training Course about Drools and jBPM5 you can find it here:

http://salaboy.com/2011/01/24/announcing-jbpm5-community-training/

http://salaboy.com/2011/02/23/drools-5-community-training-announced-roadmap/

If you find it useful please give us feedback.

Comment: wow this is useful. i was going through the documentation. now doing jboss rules 5 dev guide..Thanks a lot!